# Reverse geocoding from a GeoJSON

Tags: flutter, dart, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

For my flutter app, I need offline reverse geocoding support. To do that I've created a geojson. But couldn't find good support for reverse geocoding from a geojson in dart. How can I achieve this feature? I'm also ready to migrate other language code to dart and made own library. Any good library out there for this support?